# Utility DAL layer with entity framework 6

Tags: c#, architecture, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I'm wondering about the utility of making a dal layer with EF.
Why not calling EF directly in business layer, considering EF DBContext is a unitOfWork and List DBSet are repositories ?
So why adding an extra DAL layer, wich is finally a facade..
The only advantage i see, is in case of we have to change the data access implementation, like replace EF by Hibernate or other. But honestly, i've never seen that happen.

Comment: "calling EF directly in business layer" - where exactly ? In the business object itself ? As part of a service/transaction script that runs the business use case ? In a separate repository-like object residing in the business layer ?

Comment: @guillaume31, not the businness object itself, but from the services.  
For example :   
public OrderService(IOrderRepository repo)
{
 this.repo = repo
}
public void Save(OrderDTO order)
{
 var OrderEntity = ConvertDTOToEntity(order);
 if(OrderEntity.CheckBusinessRules())
  repo.Save(OrderEntity)
}

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/235094/ensure-that-each-class-has-only-one-responsibility-why

Answer (score 2):

Actually with a data mapper the necessity of developing a DAL is plain useless because it would contain 0 lines of code.

Everything on top of a data mapper isn't a *data access layer* but actual domain, because a data mapper implementation like an OR/M translates your objects into the underlying relational data and viceversa, and you work on top of them is to develop your domain and miss the pain of object-relational impedance.

The point of introducing the *repository pattern* on top of a data mapper is because you want to both be able to switch the underlying data store even to a non-relational one in the long run (also, switch from NoSQL to SQL, who knows!), and there's another definitive reason to introduce the repository layer in your software: **because you want to be able to mock the data store with fakes in order to unit test your domain**.

Finally, even when Entity Framework implements *unit of work* and other patterns, sometimes their implementation may not suit your own domain requirements and you need to wrap them to provide more concretion to your domain.

Comment: Agree about mock, but i think switching the underlying data remains uncommon and does'nt justify spending 20% extra time

Comment: @BobyOneKenobi Extra time today, less time tomorrow ;)

Comment: @bobyonekenobi BTW if you know how to write your code the DDD way you don't need 20℅ extra time. If it's your first time to  implement DDD maybe that time loss occurs because there's a learning curve....